# In VSCode how do you select a whole word with - in it?

Tags: ide, text-editor, visual-studio-code

IE: say I double click `"LAYOUT:MENU-TRADE":` I want to select the entire constant. Or at least the entire `MENU-TRADE` part.

[image]

In atom I can accomplish this by removing `-` as an ignored character. How is this accomplished in VSCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by customizing your `editor.wordSeparators`. Simply remove "-" from the list.

[image]